# What physical/health factors disqualify an otherwise qualified bechor from pidyon haben?

Tags: health-safety-shmira, bechor-firstborn, pidyon-haben

If a first-born son meets the qualifications for pidyon ha'ben (first born of his mother, born naturally, parents are both Yisroel), what physical health issues would "disqualify" the bechor from needing a pidyon haben. For example, if Chas v'shalom he has a disease or is ch'v blind or ch'v missing an arm would these override the need for a pidyon haben?

Comment: Welcome Benjamin G and thank you for your interesting question. Would you mind clarifying why you would think physical / health factors have any relevance to pidyon haben? Why are they any more relevant than if the baby has blond hair?

Comment: @robev probably he's making a comparison to animal bechoros

Comment: @Heshy But if so, even animal bechoros with a mum have kedushah; they just can't be brought as a korban. So still no reason to think a human baby would be any different.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very interesting [4-volume set of seforim](https://seforimcenter.com/Nishmat-Avraham--Hilchot-Refuah-4-vol.__p-9773.aspx) called Nishmas Avraham by [Rabbi Dr Avraham-Sofer Avraham](https://www.torahcafe.com/scholar/rabbi-dr-abraham-s-abraham_0000001180.html) which details medical and health based halachos. They are all available on Hebrewbooks.org - Vol, [1](https://hebrewbooks.org/51473), [2](https://hebrewbooks.org/51474), [3](https://hebrewbooks.org/51475) & [4](https://hebrewbooks.org/51472))

In the cheilek on [Yoreh Deah, siman 305](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51474&st=&pgnum=393&hilite=) it details the Laws of Pidyon Haben. It is a very compelling read and explores a number of issues. It mentions [here - (no. 2 in the Nishmas Avraham)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51474&st=&pgnum=395&hilite=) that if a child is born with terminal defects he does not undergo a pidyon haben - even if medical intervention can keep him alive for 30 days. It also mentions a case of a child that is born "ללא קיבה" - "without a stomach" (I think) and Rav Elyashiv paskened that it has the status of a 'tereifa' and if the baby lived beyond 30 days it is still exempt from a pidyon haben.

He writes ([in  gimmel](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51474&st=&pgnum=395&hilite=)) according to the Shach that in all cases of a definitive 'tereifa', even if the baby survives a long time after the 30 day period he is still exempt from the pidyon haben. This would apply even in a case of a 'sofeik tereifa' i.e. when there is a doubt if the child has a defect or not. He then goes on to cite a discussion on whether if the child lives beyond a year whether or not he still has the pidyon.

However, it would seem that he concludes:

> אבל מי שנולד טריפה מתחלת ברייתו, חייב בפדיון
>
> *But one who is born with a defect from the beginning of its creation (i.e. from birth), is obligated in a pidyon.*

I assume that means that if it is treatable and he can recover he has the pidyon, but if it is something incredibly serious we don't put the child at risk - like with the case of the baby without a stomach cited above.

Comment: Today many people are traifa and survive for years. For instance anyone who feeds directly to the stomach with a peg. He has a hole in his stomach and is definitely traifoh. I dont know the answer except traifos may be different for people. If that is the case one can never know if one is really traifo.

Comment: That's possibly part of the reasoning why in most instances of treifos we go ahead with the pidyon