# Is shalom Zachar held for treifa babies

Tags: halacha, pregnancy-birth, meal-seudah, yoreh-deah, injury

Halacha exempts baby boys with serious injuries or illnesses from Pidyon Haben (see [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/117061/33665)). My question is whether a shalom Zachar Seudat mitzvah should be held for a baby boy  like this?

Comment: A shalom zochor is not a seudas mitzvah?

Comment: The reasoning for a shalom zochor is brought in the Taz on SA YD 265:13 who writes that the practise of a shalom zochor is for people to visit the home of the newborn to comfort him over this loss of Torah. Surely this would be no different, even if a tereifa?

Comment: Practically the baby would be in a NICU or something and thus there's probably no point of doing one anyway